# Why this doesnt write "Weekend" or "even Weekend in textBox?

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, int

I tried this to write Even Weekend or Wekend in textbox and nothing appears.

```
DateTime thisDate1 = DateTime.Now;
int day = thisDate1.DayOfYear;
int week = day / 7;
bool even = true;
if ((week % 2) == 0) even = true;
if ((week % 2) == 1) even = false;

if (even == true)
{
    if ((int)thisDate1.DayOfWeek == 6) textBox1.Text = "Even Weekend";
    if ((int)thisDate1.DayOfWeek == 7) textBox1.Text = "Even Weekend";
}
if (even == false)
{
    if ((int)thisDate1.DayOfWeek == 6) textBox1.Text = "Weekend";
    if ((int)thisDate1.DayOfWeek == 7) textBox1.Text = "Weekend";
}
```

Thank you very much for every answer.

Comment: `int week = day / 7;` - week numbering isn't that simple...

Comment: Friday is only the weekend in Iceland.  Get rid of the casts.

Comment: As a general tip on the code above, using "else" would seriously improve it!

Comment: I guess thisDate1.DayOfWeek is not 6 or 7 ... have you tried to see what thisDate1.DayOfWeek return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are testing it today, on a Sunday. But `DayOfWeek.Sunday` is `0` , not `7`.

The answer is *not* to convert to int:

```
//if ((int)thisDate1.DayOfWeek == 6) textBox1.Text = "Even Weekend";
//if ((int)thisDate1.DayOfWeek == 7) textBox1.Text = "Even Weekend";
  if (thisDate1.DayOfWeek == DayofWeek.Saturday)  textBox1.Text = "Even Weekend";
  if (thisDate1.DayOfWeek == DayofWeek.Sunday)    textBox1.Text = "Even Weekend";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use Ints to check dates when they provide DayOfWeek enumerated types
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
if (even == true)
            {
                if (thisDate1.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) textBox1.Text = "Even Weekend";
                if (thisDate1.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) textBox1.Text = "Even Weekend";


        }
    if (even == false)
    {
        if (thisDate1.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) textBox1.Text = "Weekend";
        if (thisDate1.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) textBox1.Text = "Weekend";

    }
```

Why use numbers?

Comment: Why not use comments? (for general tip that doesn't answer the question)